# Split up datetime element in XML to date and time using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a date string in my XML file as

```
<DateTime>20120105T103030-0600</DateTime>
```

I want to change this using XSLT to

```
<date>20120105</date>
<time>103030</time>
```

Could any one help me split out the DateTime element to date and time using XSL. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I had a similar problem:

```
  <xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <date>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($DateTime,1,8)" />
    </date>
    <time>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($DateTime,10,6)" />
    </time>
  </xsl:template>
```

Usage:

```
<xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
  <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="LastWriteTime" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Please note that I don't care for the timezone!

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="DateTime">
        <date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'T')"/></date>
        <time><xsl:value-of 
                 select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'T'), '-')"/></time>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this sample input:

```
<root>
    <DateTime>20120105T103030-0600</DateTime>
</root>
```

Produces:

```
<date>20120105</date>
<time>103030</time>
```